# Flash: combine two BitmapData objects via max( channel )

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, alpha, bitmapdata, blit

I have two BitmapData objects with alpha channels. I'd like to combine them into a single one by using max(channel_image_one, channel_image_two) for each channel, including the alpha. Is there an easy way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's straight forward bitmapdata method to merge the Alpha chanel that way. RGB could maybe do with the help of draw() applying a blend mode, but I don't think it would work if you need a strict max per chanel).

Besides, you can create a shader thanks to [PixelBender](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender/) to perform this task. It's the perfect tool for that kind of manipulations.

Slower in performance but quicker to setup if your not used to PB you could just iterate/compare/write the pixels one by one with BitmapData.getPixel32()/setPixel32().
In case you go for that, think about using BitmapData.lock()/unlock() to boost performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want max(image_one,image_two) that should be equivalent to the [LIGHTEN](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BlendMode.html#LIGHTEN) blend mode.

Here is a snippet from [Foundation ActionScript 3.0 Image Effects](http://www.friendsofed.com/book.html?isbn=9781430218715) :

```
public function lighten(topPixel:uint, bottomPixel:uint):uint{
   return Math.max(topPixel,bottomPixel);
}
```

You can get the needed as files from the chapter 2 folder of the [source zip](http://www.friendsofed.com/downloads/9781430218715/Fdn_AS3_Image_Effects.zip).

Use Theo's advice with

- lock()
- for loops
- unlock()

for speed with BitmapData or use PixelBender. Apparently according to [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html), over 90% of the Flash Player user already use version 10.